# My clock has stopped

Tags: iphone, ios, clock, widgets

The clock widget in iOS 14.2 on my iPhone 8 has stopped:

[image: Screenshot]

How do I wind it up again? The key hole on the side of the phone just stops incoming calls.

Comment: Have you tried removing and readding it?  This problem happened **a lot** during the iOS 14 beta releases and that was the only thing found that could fix it.

Comment: *re-adding, sorry for the typo.

Comment: It seems to have restarted, overnight, without any intervention from me.